# VB.NET: Display SQL Server Table Row Count in Real Time?

Tags: sql, .net, sql-server, vb.net

I've got an app at work I support that uses a SQL Server 2008 DB (vendor created/supported app).  One of the things this app does is load records into ETL tables in the DB all day to be moved to a data warehouse.

Unfortunately, the app is having lots of problems with the ETL tables right now and the vendor has no monitoring solution.  I have no accesses to the DB to add a stored procedure or anything, but I can run a count * on the ETL tables to see if things are getting out of hand.

I have managed to write a VB.NET app that will return the COUNT of rows in these ETL tables so I can keep an eye on things, but it will only return the counts if I fire a button event.

I've never written an app that runs/updates "in real time" before, and I'm looking for some guidance on how I can create an app that would update these COUNT values in as close to real time as possible.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could achieve that by writing a Console application, since you seem used to .Net.

The console application runs and you can read the values by using console.writeline() and console.readline() in your program.cs. Or you could update the record counts in a table or send an email.

When you say real time, the console application can be scheduled to run - e.g. through creating a task in task scheduler or sql agent, or it can be run by launching the exe. A rough example is that, you could send yourself an email every 10 minutes by creating a task that launches the console ap every 10 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using a Windows Forms app, just add in a Timer object that fires the SQL query off. As an added bonus, you could include fields on the form to control how often the timer fires to get the resolution that's right for you.

You can use the Timer control in Console apps too, of course.